# How to work around amqplib's Channel#consume odd signature?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I am writing a worker that uses amqplib's Channel#consume method. I want this worker to wait for jobs and process them as soon as they appear in the queue.

I wrote my own module to abstract away ampqlib, here are the relevant functions for getting a connection, setting up the queue and consuming a message:

```js
const getConnection = function(host) {
  return amqp.connect(host);
};

const createChannel = function(conn) {
  connection = conn;
  return conn.createConfirmChannel();
};

const assertQueue = function(channel, queue) {
  return channel.assertQueue(queue);
};

const consume = Promise.method(function(channel, queue, processor) {
  processor = processor || function(msg) { if (msg) Promise.resolve(msg); };
  return channel.consume(queue, processor)
});

const setupQueue = Promise.method(function setupQueue(queue) {
  const amqp_host = 'amqp://' + ((host || process.env.AMQP_HOST) || 'localhost');

  return getConnection(amqp_host)
    .then(conn => createChannel(conn)) // -> returns a `Channel` object
    .tap(channel => assertQueue(channel, queue));
});

consumeJob: Promise.method(function consumeJob(queue) {
  return setupQueue(queue)
    .then(channel => consume(channel, queue))
  });
```

My problem is with Channel#consume's odd signature. From http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html#channel_consume:

`#consume(queue, function(msg) {...}, [options, [function(err, ok) {...}]])`

The callback is not where the magic happens, the message's processing should actually go in the second argument and that breaks the flow of promises.

This is how I planned on using it:

```
return queueManager.consumeJob(queue)
  .then(msg => {
     // do some processing
  });
```

But it doesn't work. If there are no messages in the queue, the promise is rejected and then if a message is dropped in the queue nothing happens. If there is a message, only one message is processed and then the worker stalls because it exited the "processor" function from the Channel#consume call.

How should I go about it? I want to keep the queueManager abstraction so my code is easier to reason about but I don't know how to do it... Any pointers?

Comment: The promise returned by Channel#consume is resolved when the server knows your client is a consumer of a queue, not when you get a message. The function you pass as the second argument works like an event listener (e.g. the function will be invoked multiple times) not a Promise. Promises can only be resolved once. You can use the [Channel#get](http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html#channel_get) method instead if you only want to fetch a single message off the queue (which would work with Promises).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @idbehold said, Promises can only be resolved once. If you want to process messages as they come in, there is no other way than to use this function. Channel#get will only check the queue once and then return; it wouldn't work for a scenario where you need a worker.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an option - you can present your application as a stream of some messages(or events). There is a library called [Highland](https://caolan.github.io/highland/) for this.

Your code should look like this (it isn't a finished sample, but I hope it illustrates the idea):

```
let messageStream = _((push, next) => {
  consume(queue, (msg) => {
   push(null, msg)
  })
)
// now you can operate with your stream in functional style 
message.map((msg) => msg + 'some value').each((msg) => // do something with msg)
```

This approach provides you a lot of primitives for synchronization and transformation.

Comment: Thanks, playing with Highland is on my list but I didn't get to it yet.